# Random error from Gerrit CLI over SSH: "Cannot post review"

Tags: ssh, gerrit

In our Gerrit instance (2.10), we're getting a random error (in 1 of 10 executions) while executing a command `review`

```
bash-4.1$ ssh -p 12345 gerrit@gerrit.foo.int gerrit review --label Verified=0 --message '"Build started."' 2458,2
error: Cannot post review
```

Any suggestions what might be wrong?
Looking at the source code of Gerrit, I can see this message is associated with `RestApiException`. Unfortunately, there is not a single log record in the `logs` directory containing this exception or the `Cannot post review` error.
Not sure how to increase the log level as `logging` is not there yet (my assumption):

```
bash-4.1$ ssh -p 12345 gerrit@gerrit.foo.int gerrit logging set-level
gerrit: logging: not found
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your command looks ok. Try this command once:


ssh -p 12345 gerrit@gerrit.foo.int gerrit review --label verified=0 -m '"Build started."' <Commit-id of patchset>

Comment: This problem and its solution is described by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397547/gwt-orm-ormconcurrencyexception-concurrent-modification-detected-find-the-cau/34405319#34405319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem and its solution is described by

[GWT ORM OrmConcurrencyException: Concurrent modification detected - find the cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397547/gwt-orm-ormconcurrencyexception-concurrent-modification-detected-find-the-cau/34405319#34405319)

The real problem is that `gerrit review` is not resistant to simultaneous updates of a label (e.g., `--label A=` and `--label B=`).

This was also reported as https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=3730&thanks=3730&ts=1450711628.