# GWT ORM OrmConcurrencyException: Concurrent modification detected - find the cause

Tags: java, gwt, jdbc, gerrit

In a GWT based application (Google Gerrit in particular), I'm getting an exception (while executing the `gerrit review` command):

```
com.google.gwtorm.server.OrmConcurrencyException: Concurrent modification detected
       at com.google.gwtorm.jdbc.JdbcAccess.execute(JdbcAccess.java:449)
       at com.google.gwtorm.jdbc.JdbcAccess.updateAsBatch(JdbcAccess.java:270)
       at com.google.gwtorm.jdbc.JdbcAccess.update(JdbcAccess.java:223)
```

Is there a way to identify which data in particular caused the concurrency error?

Looking at the source code of GWT ORM, I'm assuming the `UPDATE` prepared statement didn't match the data to update and as a result nothing was updated. Finally, the `OrmConcurrencyException` was thrown to inform the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when `gerrit review` is executed in parallel.

For instance, as reported at https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=3730&thanks=3730&ts=1450711628, updating a `--label` of two different labels causes this error:

```
bash-3.2$ ssh robot@gerrit.foo.int gerrit review --label Verified=-1 \
    --message '"Verified .. -1."' 2463,9 & \
    ssh robot@gerrit.foo.int gerrit review --label Tested=+1 \
    --message '"Tested .. +1."' 2463,9 &
[3] 29329
[4] 29330
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$ error: Cannot post review
one or more reviews failed; review output above

[3]   Done                    ssh robot@gerrit.foo.int gerrit review --label Verified=-1 --message '"Verified .. -1."' 2463,9
[4]   Exit 1                  ssh robot@gerrit.foo.int gerrit review --label Tested=+1 --message '"Tested .. +1."' 2463,9
```

It should be just ok to re-trigger one of the commands once again (or fix the reported issue).